# Java printf use dot as separator

Tags: java, printf

I'm looking for a way to separate like this:

```
1188957731        ----->       1.188.957.731
```

I've seen solutions to set a custom pattern but I was curious on finding a simpler solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String [] args) 
{
    int a = 1188957731, copya = a;
    Stack out = new Stack();
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    while (copya != 0)
    {
        out.push("." + (copya % 1000));
        copya /= 1000;
    }
    while (!out.isEmpty())
    {
        s.append(out.pop());
    }
    System.out.println(s.substring(1));
}
```

You could try something like this.

Comment: why to use stacks its it can only be handle by for or while loop.

Comment: you are correct, there could be other approaches, but using stack makes it more understandable and optimized. Please suggest your approach.

Comment: just figure out the length of integer placing `dot` after required no.